# how to prevent WSA from autoupdating?

Tags: windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-android

I have tried every possible option to stop the Windows Subsystem for Android (WSA) from auto-updating:

- Disabling Windows and Microsoft Store auto-updates in the registry and through group policies.
- Disabling update and background transfer services.
- Switching to a metered connection.
- Blocking WSA via the firewall.

Despite these efforts, nothing seems to be effective. The current WSA version has broken local networking, and every morning after an update, I have to reinstall the older version and then sideload Android apps all over again. Even running an Android app continuously doesn't prevent this. WSA still interrupts the app to perform its update every morning when I wake my PC from its sleep state.